# android multiple project

Tags: android, eclipse, project, multi-project

I'm working on a fairly large sized android project, with multiple apps & libs, each with their own dependencies etc.  The team working on this project is starting to grow, and it seems that the "checkout & build" dream is quickly evaporating.  Every time someone adds a project to eclipse, everyone else on the team has to do the "file import" dance.  In .net, you can just commit your sln file to source control and when people make changes to the environment, everyone stays in sync.  Is there anything like this in the android eclipse environment?  Can i just commit my entire workspace, or something, to git and have everyone just be on the same page???

Comment: To me it looks like you need external build tools (Ant or maven) to manage project dependency and apply unified solution for setup, build and release projects.

Answer (score 0):

Will this plugin do 
http://www.eclipse.org/egit/ ?

Comment: apparently... kinda of sucks, you think there'd be some eclipse equivalent of the visual studio .sln file...

Comment: As yorkw said try ant tool. It automates routine tasks very well. It requires some study though. I don't know maven but heard it's similar to ant

Comment: yes, ant is fine for building the codebase, but will it actually import the projects into eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse notice "team" http://www.vogella.com/articles/EGit/article.html

Comment: switched to IntelliJ over a year ago, never looking back to eclipse.  ever.